# powershell script file rename help

Tags: powershell, rename, file-rename

Im making a script to rename files in a folder using a preprovided prefix combined with an incrimental 6 digit value which when concatenated with the prefix gives the document title.

I need the script to iterate through the file list from a provided folder and alter each file name with the prefix incrimenting the incrimental number each time with the initial provided number being the first incriment.

I am close but i have been having some errors and im not sure where im going wrong. please advise.

```
Write-host "Please enter prefix:"
[String]$strPrefix = read-host

Write-host "Please enter incrimental value:"
[int]$intInc = read-host

Write-host "Please enter Files folder:"
[String]$strFiles =  "C:\scripts\files"
#$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $strFiles
$items = $strFiles

$intInc

#for each file in $strFiles
foreach ($file in $items )
{
    $newName = $strPrefix + ('0' * (6 - $intInc.ToSTring().Length)) + ($intInc++).ToString()

    if ($extOnly.length -eq 0) 
    {
        Rename-Item New-Name{$file -replace  '$newName'}
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-host "NewName $newName$extOnly"

        Rename-Item New-Name{$file -replace '$newName$extOnly'}
    } #end else

    $file

}#end for
```

I think im close but something is just making it fall over

Comment: Can you post the errors? what represent $extOnly variable? $items = $strFiles don't make sense!

Comment: Is `#$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $strFiles` supposed to be commented out? Why are you assigning `$items` to a string on the next line? A `foreach` on the string will only loop once.

Comment: Note that you can get rid if the `Write-Host "Please enter prefix:"` since you can pass a prompt to `Read-Host` e.g. `$strPrefix = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter prefix"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Write-host "Please enter prefix:"
[String]$strPrefix = read-host

Write-host "Please enter incrimental value:"
[int]$intInc = read-host

Write-host "Please enter Files folder:"
[String]$strFiles =  "C:\temp\files"

$files = get-childitem $strFiles -recurse

ForEach ($file in $files) {
$intIncPadded = "{0:D6}" -f $intInc
$newName = "$strPrefix$intIncPadded" + $file.Extension
Rename-Item $file.FullName $newName 
$intInc = $intInc + 1
}
```

Comment: rite-host "Please enter Files folder:"
[String]$strFiles =  "C:\temp\files"  - Shouldn't there be a Read-Host in there?

Comment: thanks, I added the padding and readhost for the scripts folder myself but this way looks a little allot more tidy. thanks

Comment: You're welcome... any chance of marking this as the answer? :)